# Resolving the forces into components

Tags: mathematics, kinematics

okay so I am really struggling to see how to resolve the Normal reaction force and Weight into the r and theta direction please? Why is it that the angle is taken to the left of N and right of mg please?[image]

Can someone give me some tips on this please? And why isn’t the N force resolved with the angle to the right of it attached to the theta line please?

Comment: Am I missing the question? Isn't it N*cos(theta)?

Comment: Hi, so I just don’t get why the N and mg are resolved like that, could it be done  y resolving against the theta axis too please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to review the trigonometric functions. In your question, assume the forces are to be resolved into component forces along the orthogonal axes r & q,

$\sum F_r = Rcos\theta - Ncos\theta = (R-N)cos\theta$

$\sum F_q = F + Rsin\theta - Nsin\theta = F + (R-N)sin\theta$

[image] [image]

If you have any doubt, you can prove the validity of the component forces by the "rule of the right triangle":

$c^2 = a^2 + b^2$, thus

$R = \sqrt{R^2sin^2\theta + R^2cos^2\theta} = \sqrt{R^2(sin^2\theta + cos^2\theta)}= \sqrt{R^2} = R$, **CHECK!**

Comment: Hi r13, thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome.